# How to write T-SQL query to calculate amount sum that will be 31 days past due or greater on the last day of the month?

Tags: t-sql, conditional-statements

I am tring to calculate the amount sum that will be 31 days past due or greater on the last day of the month. So far I have done this but I am not sure how do I apply the second condition  for the last day of the month. Thanks for the tips

```
SELECT SUM(balance_amount) AS total_amount FROM MyTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,date_due,date_paid) >= 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Well clearly, on the last day of any month,  the amounts that are 31 days overdue are the amounts for transactions dated 31 days prior to the end of the month, unless they have been paid.

```
Select Sum(t.Amount) - Sum(p.Amount)
From invoices t join payments p
    On p.AccountNum = t.AccountNum
Where t.InvoiceDate < DateAdd(month, 1 + datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)-32
```

The expression in the last line,   `DateAdd(month, 1+datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)`  is the first of next month
I don't see (without access to your schema), how you can tell, just from the balance on the account, how much of the balance will be 31 days overdue at the end of the current month.

Comment: Charles, thanks so much. As you said I have few more attributes that I need to take into consideration. But your tips certainly helps me to start from.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Select Dateadd(d,-DATEPART(d,DateAdd(m,1,getdate())),DateAdd(m,1,getdate())) as [Last Day of Month]
```

You work out the last day of the CURRENT month by adding 1 month to today's date and then subtracting the number of days in this particular month.  Try some edge cases like 28th Feb e.t.c.